# Pull Gitlab specific docker image tag version

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ce

How can i pull gitlab specifc docker image?

I am using Gitlab Community Edition and I have tried many ways to do so but I didn't find any solution or documentation

It looks like there is just gitlab latest version tag on dockerhub repo

```
pull gitlab/gitlab-ce:12.5
Error response from daemon: manifest for gitlab/gitlab-ce:12.5 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Search the tag on this page

https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/tags?page=1&name=12.5

That command will use dockerhub to pull. The image you want is

gitlab/gitlab-ce:12.5.10-ce.0

That image is really old though so unless you have a good reason to use that image. Use another tag on the link above